# JavaScript $.getJSON Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a problem with a piece of JavaScript code - a snippet is shown below. Basically the code is issuing a getJSON request to a rails controller and then should process the returned data, building an HTML table and then embedding it in a Div. It doesn't work. I have tried stepping through it with alerts, etc - all to no avail. The data is retrieved from the rails controller and I can verify that. I have placed the piece of code that issues and processes the getJSON request in the niddle of the Rails Welcome page - this is not all mine. The code is below:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails: Welcome aboard</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Verdana";
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #333;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 28px;
        color: #000;
      }

      a  {color: #03c}
      a:hover {
        background-color: #03c;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
      }


      #page {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        width: 750px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }

      #content {
        float: left;
        background-color: white;
        border: 3px solid #aaa;
        border-top: none;
        padding: 25px;
        width: 500px;
      }

      #sidebar {
        float: right;
        width: 175px;
      }

      #footer {
        clear: both;
      }


      #header, #about, #getting-started {
        padding-left: 75px;
        padding-right: 30px;
      }


      #header {
        background-image: url("images/rails.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top left;
        height: 64px;
      }
      #header h1, #header h2 {margin: 0}
      #header h2 {
        color: #888;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
      }


      #about h3 {
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      #about-content {
        background-color: #ffd;
        border: 1px solid #fc0;
        margin-left: -55px;
        margin-right: -10px;
      }
      #about-content table {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 11px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      #about-content td {
        padding: 10px;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
      }
      #about-content td.name  {color: #555}
      #about-content td.value {color: #000}

      #about-content ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
      }

      #about-content.failure {
        background-color: #fcc;
        border: 1px solid #f00;
      }
      #about-content.failure p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
      }


      #getting-started {
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin-top: 25px;
        padding-top: 15px;
      }
      #getting-started h1 {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      #getting-started h2 {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #333;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
      }
      #getting-started ol {
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
      }
      #getting-started li {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #888;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
      }
      #getting-started li h2 {
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #333;
      }
      #getting-started li p {
        color: #555;
        font-size: 13px;
      }


      #sidebar ul {
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
      }
      #sidebar ul h3 {
        margin-top: 25px;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      }
      #sidebar li {
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      #sidebar ul.links li {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }

    </style>

    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function about() {
        info = document.getElementById('about-content');
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          { xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
        else
          { xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        xhr.open("GET","rails/info/properties",false);
        xhr.send("");
        info.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        info.style.display = 'block'
      }
    </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

           alert('Start of JSON Routine');

           $(document).ready( function() {

             alert('Attach a JQuery Live event to the button');

             $('#getdata-button').live('click', function() {

               alert("Get JSON data");

               $.getJSON('http://0.0.0.0:3000/getjson/1', function(data) {

                  alert('Processing returned JSON data');

                  var tmp = '<table border=1>';

                  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                  {
                    tmp = tmp +'<tr>';
                      tmp = tmp + '<td>' + data[i].book.price         + '</td>';
                      tmp = tmp + '<td>' + data[i].book.title         + '</td>';
                      tmp = tmp + '<td>' + data[i].book.author        + '</td>';
                      tmp = tmp + '<td>' + data[i].book.ISBN          + '</td>';
                      tmp = tmp + '<td>' + data[i].book.yearPublished + '</td>';
                      tmp = tmp + '<td>' + data[i].book.volume        + '</td>';
                      tmp = tmp + '<td>' + data[i].book.publisher     + '</td>';
                      tmp = tmp + '<td>' + data[i].book.edition       + '</td>';
                      tmp = tmp + '<td><a href=# onclick=\"alert('+ i +')\">View</a></td>'; 
                    tmp = tmp + '</tr>';
                  }

                  tmp = tmp + '</table>';

                  alert('About to insert Table into DOM in content Div');

                  $('#showdata').html(tmp);

               }); //getJSON        end
             });   //getdata-button end
           });     //document.ready end

           alert('End of JSON routine'); 

        </script>

  </head>



  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <ul id="sidebar-items">
          <li>
            <h3>Browse the documentation</h3>
            <ul class="links">
              <li><a href="http://api.rubyonrails.org/">Rails API</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/">Ruby standard library</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/">Ruby core</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://guides.rubyonrails.org/">Rails Guides</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>





        <a href="#" id="getdata-button">Get JSON Data</a>

        <script>alert("Before the JMC div");</script>

        <div id="showdata">JMC</div>


        <script>alert("Past the JMC div");</script>


       <div id="content">


          <h1>Welcome aboard</h1>
          <h2>You&rsquo;re riding Ruby on Rails!</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="about">
          <h3><a href="rails/info/properties" onclick="about(); return false">About your application&rsquo;s environment</a></h3>
          <div id="about-content" style="display: none"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="getting-started">
          <h1>Getting started</h1>
          <h2>Here&rsquo;s how to get rolling:</h2>

          <ol>
            <li>
              <h2>Use <code>rails generate</code> to create your models and controllers</h2>
              <p>To see all available options, run it without parameters.</p>
            </li>

            <li>
              <h2>Set up a default route and remove or rename this file</h2>
              <p>Routes are set up in config/routes.rb.</p>
            </li>

            <li>
              <h2>Create your database</h2>
              <p>Run <code>rake db:migrate</code> to create your database. If you're not using SQLite (the default), edit <code>config/database.yml</code> with your username and password.</p>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="footer">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSON data I get back when I just invoked the URL/ Controller action directly from the browser:

```
[
   {
      "book":{
         "price":"25.52",
         "created_at":"2011-10-27T22:35:04Z",
         "ISBN":"",
         "author":"Obie Fernandez",
         "title":"Rails 3 Way, The (2nd Edition)",
         "updated_at":"2011-10-27T22:35:04Z",
         "yearPublished":"2010",
         "id":1,
         "publisher":"Addison-Wesley",
         "volume":"2",
         "edition":"second edition"
      }
   },
   {
      "book":{
         "price":"23.94",
         "created_at":"2011-10-27T22:39:37Z",
         "ISBN":"",
         "author":"Michael Hartl",
         "title":"Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example",
         "updated_at":"2011-10-27T22:39:37Z",
         "yearPublished":"2010",
         "id":2,
         "publisher":"Addison-Wesley",
         "volume":"",
         "edition":"first edition"
      }
   },
   {
      "book":{
         "price":"24.97",
         "created_at":"2011-10-27T22:42:42Z",
         "ISBN":"",
         "author":"Cloves Carneiro Jr. and Rida Al Barazi",
         "title":"Beginning Rails 3 ",
         "updated_at":"2011-10-27T22:42:42Z",
         "yearPublished":"2009",
         "id":3,
         "publisher":"Apress",
         "volume":"",
         "edition":"first edition"
      }
   }
]
```

Anything else that might be useful. The Rails logs show the request being handled correctly.

When I step through the script, the alerts come up in a starnge sequence:

THe first alert I get is "Here at start of JSON Routine", followed by "Finished document ready routine" and then "Attach a JQuery Live event to the button". I then click the button for getdata and then a # appears at the end of the URL and then nothing.

MOved the script into the head - same outcome.

SWitched #content to #showdata - same outcome.

Final Edit:

The problem is solved thanks to the input of many people.

There were a number of issues, but the final issue was a same origin error in that the URL on the getJSON request was different to the URL making the request. The request had 0.0.0.0:3000/getjson/1 whereas the requesting URL was localhost:3000/getjson/1.  Very hard to spot and the lack of return / status info with getJSON made it more difficult.  Anyway thanks is due to all contributors, who all made valid contributions. I hope I have the expertise to contribute myself someday.

Comment: Cross Domain issue, Same Origin Policy, etc. This will not work without JSONP

Comment: @MikeStewart "The data is retrieved from the controler [...]"

Comment: Can you give us an example of your json data?  Are you getting any errors?  What exactly isn't 'working'?

Comment: Oh, interesting. Then my guess is that data is not an instance of Array

Comment: Maybe that script tag is replacing itself,put the code in the head and try? the script is contained in #content

Comment: Is the returned data valid JSON? could you give an example. It might be bailing out b/c it cannot properly parse the json. Do you get to your second alert?

Comment: are you seeing any of the alerts?

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end here: `alert('About to insert Table into DOM in content Div')`

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/RtCaB/.

Comment: iWasRobbed - if only that was the cause. Good spot but see the sequence of alert messages at the end of my post.

Comment: the problem with `$.getJSON` is that it doesn't allow you to specify an error handler. Try using the low-level `$.ajax` method with success and error handlers and see what kind of errors are reported. Inspect `jqXHR.responseText` to see if you're getting what you expect, and then try `JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText)` to see if it will parse it correctly. If you are using a new enough version of jQuery, you could also just chain a `.fail()` (i.e. `$.getJSON(...).fail(function(jqXHR,status,error){})`) to see what's happening

Comment: the sequence of messages is as expected. Your `alert('Finished document ready routine');` is outside `$(document).ready(...)` so it shows up before `"Attach a JQuery Live event to the button"` which is inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I am a bit new to Javascript - how can you step through or trace the code.

Comment: The sequence of Alert Messages is strange - its like as if its falling through to the end of the nested functions, ignoring the intermediate code. Often got this in the past when a : or ; was missing - just cant see it.

Comment: You need to understand that `$(document).ready(function(){...})` means "place `function(){...}` in a queue and call it when the DOM is ready". That line DOESN'T execute your function. So, the sequence of alerts makes sense: (1)first alert, (2)place callback function containing second alert in a queue to be executed at a future time when DOM is ready (3), third alert. (1) and (3) will happen before the callback in (2) is executed.

Comment: Is there any way that I can restructure the code to achieve the same objective. I am really under time pressure now. ampersand

Comment: Added in latest version of code, that includes the whole of the Rails welcome page tangle - definitely not UJS !

Comment: @JoeMcGouran: Please stop trying to edit the first answer with the version information. Either comment on the answer, or edit the question to contain the extra information. Adding the information to the answer is invalid and will keep getting rejected.

Comment: I have now tried the code with both the getJSON call and in a second mode, just loading in the data returned by the server. The second version works, the first still hangs on the call. The code seems basically okay, the problem lies somewhere else - any suggestions about further steps.

Comment: The server returns a type 200 message to the browser - this is shown in red with an x in Firebug console.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the rails controller code - I use render :json => @book to generate the JSON data.

Comment: In the console each request is shown as being success ful with 200 status code.

Comment: THe Browser is Firefox 7.0.1 running on Ubuntu canonical 1.0.

Comment: Joe: I added a working answer (tested on my Rails server) to the answers below.

Comment: I've implemented it - got status code of 0, but Firebug shows successful 200.

Comment: Thanks folks - problem solved. See final edit above for explanation. Again many thanks to you all for such valuable contributions.

Comment: What do I do with my downvoted correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright Joe, you need to start with the simplest case possible... clean up all of your HTML and get rid of everything that you do not need.  I tested this and verified that it works on my local Rails server.

I mocked up the Rails controller action to return your JSON data using:

```
  def getjson
    json_data = '[{ "book": { "price": 18.75, "title": "Moby Dick", "author": "Herman Melville", "ISBN": "0393972836", "yearPublished": 2001, "volume": 1, "publisher": "W. W. Norton & Company", "edition": "2nd Edition" }}]'
    render :json => json_data, :status => :ok
  end
```

You shouldn't need to change your Rails controller code since you said it was working.  I just wanted to show you how I mocked it up for your future reference.

Now, replace the contents of your HTML file with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>JSON Test example</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#getdata-button').live('click', function() {
                // clear out the old data:
                $('#content').html('');

                alert("Getting JSON data");

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/getjson/1',
                    success: function(json) {
                        console.log(json);
                        alert('Processing returned JSON data');

                        var tmp = '<table border=1>';

                        for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                            tmp = tmp + '<tr>';
                            tmp = tmp + '<td>' + json[i].book.price + '</td>';
                            tmp = tmp + '<td>' + json[i].book.title + '</td>';
                            tmp = tmp + '<td>' + json[i].book.author + '</td>';
                            tmp = tmp + '<td>' + json[i].book.ISBN + '</td>';
                            tmp = tmp + '<td>' + json[i].book.yearPublished + '</td>';
                            tmp = tmp + '<td>' + json[i].book.volume + '</td>';
                            tmp = tmp + '<td>' + json[i].book.publisher + '</td>';
                            tmp = tmp + '<td>' + json[i].book.edition + '</td>';
                            tmp = tmp + '<td><a href=# onclick=\"alert(' + i + ')\">View</a></td>';
                            tmp = tmp + '</tr>';
                        }

                        tmp = tmp + '</table>';

                        alert('About to insert the following data into DOM: ' + tmp);

                        // Show the div we are looking for in the browser's console
                        console.log($('#content'));

                        $('#content').html(tmp);
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        alert('There was an error: ' + response.status);
                    }
                }); // $.ajax end
            }); //getdata-button end

        }); //document.ready end
    </script>
  </head>

  <body> 
    <a href="#" id="getdata-button">Get JSON Data</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="content">The data will be placed here.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice that I am using the `$.ajax` method which allows me to specify an error handler callback.  I would recommend using this way of doing things until you become more familiar with jQuery and feel confident that you can start using the other AJAX helpers.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'll have a go at that, the code is stuck on the getJSON call. Why do you use :status => :ok in the controller ?

Comment: This is a good call.  'Success' is relative - you need to actually get at the response.

Comment: Getting an error from my implementation. Error status code of 0.

Comment: If the javascript error alert is showing up, that means you have an error in your controller.  I use `:status => :ok` because it sends an HTTP 200 response back to the browser.  Here's a list of Rails statuses mapped to HTTP statuses: http://www.codyfauser.com/2008/7/4/rails-http-status-code-to-symbol-mapping

Comment: I got that stuff from the Guides. The status on all the HTTP reolies has been 200, without fail. As I say the error status code output is 0 from the response.status property. I am pretty sure that the data is right - I am using Firefox 7.9.1. - is there anything I can do to it, any setting, etc. that you want me to check. I would be surprised if it was the same origin policy issue, given that the setup is on my laptop.

Comment: iWasRobbed - problem finally solved - see final edit above for explanation. However, your contribution proved crucial. I will use the Ajax approach going forward - much more explicit and informative. Now to finish off the AJAX CrUD. Posted a "Sequel" request on Stackoverflow. Again many thanks.

Comment: In the future, I would leave off the domain/IP and just leave it as a relative path.  So just make it `/getjson/1` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:3000/getjson/1` or `http://localhost:3000/getjson/1`

Comment: Good advice - now for the next challenge - bit of a treadmill iWasRobbed. Did you look at jsb.erb Sequel posting ?

Answer (score 2):

This is most related to same origin policy (cross domain blocking) and can be resolved by using a JSONP call. Add a `?callback=?` to the end of the URL:

```
    $(document).ready( function() { 
         alert('Attach a JQuery Live event to the button'); 
         $('#getdata-button').live('click', function() { 
           $.getJSONP('http://0.0.0.0:3000/getjson/1?callback=?, function(data) { 

             // ... Omiting for brevity

              $('#content').html(tmp); 

           }); 
         }); 
       });
```

Comment: or adding a access-control-allow-origin header in the response

Comment: THe setup is that I am using localhost with the Browser, WebBrick Server and Rails Server all in the one machine.

Comment: MOved the script above the content Div - same issues.

Comment: Which version would you recommend. Currently have the version I installed as part of Gem install instruction gtom Github site. Thanks for coming back - see latest version of code. In JSFiddle he simulated the getJSON connection - not really equivalent, unfortunately.

Comment: Why do I get tracking alerts etc, now that the function is in the Head section. I thought a function in there only triggered when called.

Comment: I now believe that the problem is caused by the getJSON function not completing properly. The request is being processed at the server and the information is being returned to the browser. The format of the data looks okay. It just gets lost at that point. Puzzling ?

Comment: I am using Firefox 7.0.1. and the server is sending bach HTTP code 200 in all cases. I have even taken this data and simulated a feed inti the code - the code works. The getJSON function call is hanging and not completing, I do not know if there is some condition or browser setting or browser bug that causes this. Similar problem happend with an implementation using $,ajax to get the data - response.status property returns 0. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Tried the $.getJSONP method - did not even get a 200 HTTP request and the server received nothing. Puzzling RCDMK ?

Comment: Folks,the final cause of the problem was violation of the Same Origin Policy. See final edit above for explanation. Many thanks to everyonwe for their input - much appreciated.

Comment: I've said it since the begining and was downvoted for it. What now? Lucky you I'm not so upset. Kidding.

Comment: RCDMK - now that you have shown your insight and prescience - why dont you look at my other problem : on the AJAX CRUD and js.erb files - shouldbe a cakewalk.

Comment: Sorry but I can only do a prediction per day. kidding again. ;)   I don't have any RoR knowledge and the problem don't seem to be js related.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#content')` doesn't seem to exist.

EDIT

After another look, it seems to problem hinges on the button `click` event not firing. Since this is added via `live`, and as another user has posted, works on jsfiddle: I wonder what version of jQuery you are using? Looks like it could be very old indeed. Try upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: Ha ha.  Wood for the trees.  Although - in that case, it's trying to replace itself.  @JoeMcGouran : try changing `$('#content').html(tmp);` to `$('#content').append(tmp);`

Comment: Tried that - seemed to make no difference.

Comment: Any way of achieving the same thing in a different - less nested way. Any ideas.

Comment: As the OP keeps try to say (by editing this answer) the jquery version is 1.7.1

Comment: Sorry, @JonEgerton, I don't understand.  I can't see any reference to a jquery version number anywhere on this page.

Comment: @graphicdivine: The OP keeps trying to add an edit to this answer stating that the version is 1.7.1, and it keeps being rejected. I thought I'd add the information.

Comment: H problem seems to lie with the getJSON call, in that it is received at the server, processed and a type 200 HTTP message is issued. Then nothing. Somehow the message is not gettinto the browser code. I have substsituted a simulated get and the code executes correctly. Anybody else have this issue. I am using Firefox.

Comment: @JoeMcGouran what do you get if you change `alert('Processing returned JSON data');` into `alert(data);` ?

Comment: It never gets that far - stuck on the getJSON call - see other discussions - thanks.

Comment: Problem solved - see final edit above for explanation. My thanks to everyone for their valuable contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is being refreshed and the data is likely getting dropped.  Try:

```
$('#getdata-button').live('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();     
}
```

Comment: TRied that - made no difference. Is there any other way of restructuring the code to achieve the same object of getting and processing the JSON data - assume that the rails app is not the problem for the moment.

Comment: There must be another error on the page.  The `preventDefault` will solve the issue where you "click the button for getdata and then a # appears at the end of the URL and then nothing."  You should at least get the `error` or `success` alert.  If not, then try also, setting `timeout: 5000` in your `ajax` call.

Comment: Brett - should there be a right bracket after the right curly bracket. THe problem is with the getJSON function, hanging, even though the server is sending back a HTTP code 200 reply. However, every little bit helps - much appreciated.